# Visual Studio designer view source is partially black

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms, windows-7-x64

I am developing website in ASP.NET web-forms. When I go to the source of the designer of my default.aspx file it shows like this:

[image]

I restarted the visual studio and reloaded the project, but its still not working. Please tell me what is happening?

I am using VS2012 on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Comment: Upgrade your video card driver.

Comment: @SLaks: it is up-to-date. I recently updated it. I am using ATI Mobility Radeon 45xx series. There is no new update available on ATI site.

Comment: What do you see if you open that file in notepad?

Comment: I do have to point out that using the Designer View in ASP.NET (in my experience) is a losing battle. Eventually things just don't look right in it, even if they do show up properly on the actual web pages. Just beware that it is quirky, that is all!

Comment: @Aishwarya: I think its because of low memory. do you have enough memory while running this application?

Comment: @CDspace: Its showing the expected source.

Comment: @Sudhakar: thanks,your idea worked. Add it as answer. I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because of low memory. do you have enough memory while running this application. Please Check.

Comment: yup this was the case. I turned off all of the programs and then restarted Visual Studio. Thanks :)